# Вывод из бд самых обсуждаемых постов

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, есть две таблицы posts & comments

posts:

```
    |id|text|
    | 1| ...|
    | 2| ...|
    | 3| ...|
    | 4| ...|
```

comments:

```
|post_id|text|user_name|
|   3   |....| ivan    |
|   2   |....| ivan2   |
|   3   |....| ivan    |
|   2   |....| ivan2   |
|   1   |....| ivan    |
|   3   |....| ivan3   |
```

Нужно выбрать только те посты у кого больше комментариев и сортировать по количестве комментариев, в результате posts должен выглядеть так:

```
|id|text|comment_count|
| 3| ...|      3      |
| 2| ...|      2      |
| 1| ...|      1      |
```

Спасибо за ранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На первый взгляд, вам нужны так называемые агрегатные запросы, которые позволяют группировать результаты по значению одного или нескольких полей и применять функции к "сворачиваемым" множествам в других полях. Подобный запрос:

```
SELECT p.id, p.`text`, COUNT(c.post_id) AS comment_count
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

сначала соберет все записи комментариев с соответствующими им постами, затем сгруппирует по постам (`GROUP BY p.id`) и применит функцию подсчета количества сгруппированных записей.

Однако, если вы собираетесь исполнять этот запрос часто, то вам вряд ли подойдет этото подход в виду ресурсоемкости. База данных при этом полностью соединит две таблицы, пройдясь по всем записям как в одной, так и в другой; это не очень хорошо (очень не хорошо) с точки зрения производительности. Поэтому чаще всего применяют подход с кэшированием: в таблицу постов добавляется отдельное целочисленное поле (`post_count(int)`), которое инкрементируется при добавлении комментария. Это шаг в стороноу денормализации БД, однако он позволяет осуществлять быстрые выборки без объединения таблиц.

Совсем по-хорошему, конечно, такие вещи должны просто лежать в кэше.

Comment: Спасибо @Etki , я почему то думал будет не профессиональным если в posts создам еще одну ячейку для хранения количество комментариев и каждый раз при добавлении комментария обновлять эту ячейку. Думал это круто).

Comment: @bemulima Этому посвящен третий абзац, это самое нормальное решение из быстрых.